# Histogram Plot for RGB values in WinRT App

Tags: c#, windows-8, plot, windows-runtime, histogram

I'm having an issue with creating a histogram representation of an image in a WinRT app. What I'd like to make consists of four histogram plots for Red, Green, Blue, Luminosity for an image.

My main issue is how to actually draw a picture of that Histogram so I could show it on the screen. My code so far is pretty... messy, I've searched a lot for this topic, mostly my results consisted of code in Java, which I'm trying somehow to translate it in C#, but API is pretty different... Had an attempt from AForge as well but that's winforms...

Here's my messy code, I know it looks bad but I'm striving to make this work first :

```
public static WriteableBitmap CreateHistogramRepresentation(long[] histogramData, HistogramType type)
    {
        //I'm trying to determine a max height of a histogram bar, so
        //I could determine a max height of the image that then I'll remake it
        //at a lower resolution :
        var max = histogramData[0];

        //Determine the max value, the highest bar in the histogram, the initial height of the image.
        for (int i = 0; i < histogramData.Length; i++)
        {
            if (histogramData[i] > max)
                max = histogramData[i];
        }

        var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(256, 500);

        //Set a color to draw with according to the type of the histogram :
        var color = Colors.White;
        switch (type)
        {
            case HistogramType.Blue :
                {
                    color = Colors.RoyalBlue;
                    break;
                }
            case HistogramType.Green:
                {
                    color = Colors.OliveDrab;
                    break;
                }
            case HistogramType.Red:
                {
                    color = Colors.Firebrick;
                    break;
                }
            case HistogramType.Luminosity:
                {
                    color = Colors.DarkSlateGray;
                    break;
                }
        }

        //Compute a scaler to scale the bars to the actual image dimensions :
        var scaler = 1;
        while (max/scaler > 500)
        {
            scaler++;
        }

        var stream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
        var streamBuffer = new byte[stream.Length];

        //Make a white image initially :
        for (var i = 0; i < streamBuffer.Length; i++)
        {
            streamBuffer[i] = 255;
        }

        //Color the image :
        for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) // i = column
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < histogramData[i] / scaler; j++) // j = line
            {
                streamBuffer[j*256*4 + i] = color.B; //the image has a  256-pixel width
                streamBuffer[j*256*4 + i + 1] = color.G;
                streamBuffer[j*256*4 + i + 2] = color.R;
                streamBuffer[j*256*4 + i + 2] = color.A;
            }
        }

        //Write the Pixel Data into the Pixel Buffer of the future Histogram image :
        stream.Seek(0, 0);
        stream.Write(streamBuffer, 0, streamBuffer.Length);

        return bitmap.Flip(WriteableBitmapExtensions.FlipMode.Horizontal);
    }
```

This creates a pretty bad histogram representation, it doesn't even colour it with an corresponding colour... It's not working properly, I'm working on it to fix it...

If you can contribute with a link you might know any code for a histogram representation for WinRT apps or everything else is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a third party control? http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-8/controls/chart.aspx

Comment: Try using the WriteableBitmapEx CodePlex project - it's actually very easy to use and gets rid of a lot of the cruft you need to do. http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for the WriteableBitmap Extension, I've already used that in other parts of my project but... I'm clumsy, I forgot totally of that DrawLine method that did my job. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While you could use a charting control as JP Alioto pointed out, histograms tend to represent a *lot* of data. In your sample alone you're rendering 256 bars * 4 axis (R,G,B,L). The problem with charting controls is that they usually like to be handed collections (or arrays) of hydrated data, which they draw, and which they tend to keep in memory. A histogram like yours would need to have 1024 objects in memory (256 * 4) and passed to the chart as a whole. It's just not a good use of memory management.

The alternative of course is to draw it yourself. But as you've found, pixel-by-pixel drawing can be a bit of a pain. The best answer - in my opinion - is to agree with Shahar and recommend you use WriteableBitmapEx on CodePlex.

http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com

WriteableBitmapEx includes methods for drawing shapes like lines and rectangles that are very very fast. You can draw the data as you enumerate it (instead of having to have it all in memory at one time) and the result is a nice compact image that is already "bitmap cached" (meaning it renders very fast since it doesn't have to redrawn on each frame).

Dev support, design support and more awesome goodness on the way: http://bit.ly/winappsupport